# Is there any point in skinning animals after I've made all the pouches?

Tags: far-cry-3

I already have all the ammo pouches, rucksacks, etc. (well it says Owned All against each one in the menu). Is there any reason I should still skin animals?

I could sell the skins, but that's a laborious process as they aren't linked to the quick sell option so I'd have to do it manually for each. Also I'm never short of cash - if anything I tend to get to much cash I can't spend it all!

**Is there any benefit to hunting and keeping skins now?**

I'm thinking its possible some more equipment options might open up later, as is the case with weapons, or there may be a bonus in collecting X amounts of skins, but if not I'll just sell everything and spend the cash on flamethrower ammo instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no use for skins other than crafting and selling. If you've crafted all of the items and don't need the money, then you don't need to skin killed animals.

Comment: Ah fair enough then. More flamethrower ammo and Molotov's it is then!

Answer (score 0):

Well, all you can do now is basically craft shots, and special arrows: 1 Grenade = Grenade arrow, etc, and different shots. Other than that, you can't do much.